# An accepted answer was deleted yet the user was not deleted

Tags: support, deleted-answers, accepted-answer

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61670459/nodejs-must-use-import-to-load-es-module/70635093) held [G Clark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5550852/g-clark)'s post as the accepted answer for nearly two years with ~40 upvotes. I now notice that their answer has disappeared even though G Clark's account still exists with their answer gone from their profile.

It was my understanding that accepted answers couldn't be deleted based on [this Stack Overflow Help Page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Their answer was [archived](https://newbedev.com/nodejs-must-use-import-to-load-es-module) on **newbedev.com**. I've gone ahead and [reposted their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70635093/12464931). The only problem with doing this is that my answer is now near the bottom due to the many posts that precede it (most of them not being as useful or only related to specific JavaScript technologies).

Why was their answer deleted when it was widely accepted and is there a way to reinstate it? The post is still getting a great amount of traffic with 130k views as of the time of this meta post and I want to make sure that the information that was most useful is a little more easy to find for new seekers.

Comment: There is a comment under that answer from two days ago. Maybe the commenter not only pointed out an issue but also flagged the answer for mod attention. Once it ends up in the mod queue you may hope the mod makes the right judgement call, give or take an occasional mis-click.

Comment: FYI, if you are going to repost someone else's answer, with no additional work, because (for some reason it has been removed) I would recommend posting it as a community wiki answer. Even though you cite them, you contributed no additional work in your own answer.

Comment: @Larnu Did not know about that, thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer was flagged as "Not an answer".

On flagged content, moderator tools show only the text, not the votes or the links unless we expand the answer. It's probably deliberate, though (some old high-voted answers are link-only or don't qualify as answers in nowadays site standards, and should go)

This answer started by "*I ran your code with no problem*" which is not a good sign, means "can't reproduce the problem".

Then there's advice on what to check on the environment. Again, not a definitive answer for me. That's why I deleted it, like hundreds of others which state "your code works" that are downvoted instead.

Here's how the answer shows in our tools by default:

[image]

Only the checkmark could have given a hint that the answer wasn't that bad. Can be overlooked if the mod is trigger happy.

If there's a consensus for undeletion, fine by me. But such answers are likely to be flagged (and deleted) again.

Comment: The fact that the mod dashboard doesn't show more context is forever a disappointment.

Comment: well, it allows to see a lot of flag in a tiny space. The votes are missing in the compact form, though

Comment: The irony... the only times I've ever been bold enough to flag "Not an Answer" I was summarily review banned.

Comment: that would be very surprising that you've been banned for one wrong NAA flag, really.

Answer (score 22):

It was flagged as not an answer, and another mod marked it helpful and deleted the post. The answer, however, is very much an answer, so I've gone ahead and undeleted it, and deleted your repost in the process now that it's no longer necessary.

Also note that reposting answers deleted for moderation reasons is generally frowned upon, even when the removal reason was incorrect, like it was here. The better option would've been to flag, or like you've already done in this case, ask on meta. This gets attention on the post, and effectively a second investigation

And to answer your title,

> An accepted answer was deleted yet the user was not deleted

In general, (accepted) answer removal != user removal. A user can be removed without their answer being removed, and vice versa, for any number of reasons. However, mistakes do happen, and while infrequent, that seems to have happened here. What that mistake was, however, is a question I can't answer. Could be a mis-click, a wrong judgement call, misreading, etc.; I'm not gonna speculate on what could've happened here, because it's kinda pointless coming from me.

Comment: I'm not going to talk about moderation techniques; but it seems likely to me OP couldn't tell why it was gone. One of the annoying design flaws in stackexchange is until you get to 10K you can't always see your own deleted posts when you need to.

Comment: @Joshua You can always see your own posts. You just need a link to the question, which the user must've had to repost. (Note: There's a plan to give you a list of all your deleted posts no matter your rep, and I think it'll be in place before the end of the month.)

Comment: @Laurel OP of the meta post is the OP of the source question. They found the answer by using one of the (garbage, may I add) scrapers to get the source of the answer. No direct link involved, no deletion reason seen.